# Bitbucket pipeline fails to install angular cli?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

We have the following Bitbucket pipeline that runs sanity check on our Bitbucket branches

```
image: node:9.8.0
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
        - cat /etc/apt/sources.list
        - echo "deb http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list
        - echo "deb-src http://ftp.ch.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
        - echo "deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
        - echo "deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
        - cat /etc/apt/sources.list
        - apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y gconf-service libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxss1 libxtst6 libappindicator1 libnss3 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation lsb-release xdg-utils wget
        - npm i npm@latest -g
        - npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli@7.3.9
        - cd /some_path
        - npm install
        - ng test --browsers=ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox --watch=false
        - ng build --prod=true --configuration=sbox
```

It fails on

```
+ npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli@7.3.9
TypeError: Cannot destructure property `stat` of 'undefined' or 'null'.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/node-gyp/lib/index.js:2:29)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:660:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:501:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:493:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:593:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/run-script/lib/run-script-pkg.js:4:55)
    at Module._compile (module.js:649:30)
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:163
      throw new Error('call config.load() before reading values')
      ^
Error: call config.load() before reading values
    at Config.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/config/lib/index.js:163:13)
    at process.errorHandler (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/error-handler.js:171:32)
    at process.emit (events.js:180:13)
    at process._fatalException (bootstrap_node.js:431:27)
```

Supposedly, this used to work, so why is it broken now?

Comment: We seem to have some sort of same problem we install the latest version of NPM and that actually already fails with forbidden. Npm released it yesterday. So I think there is an issue there. I would advise to go for a fixed version or maybe if possible for lts (not sure if thats posible with npm -i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old versions of node can't always run the latest npm. npm 7.x only [guarantees support for node >= 10](https://github.com/npm/cli/blob/v7.0.0/package.json#L219).

Remove `npm i npm@latest -g` to use the package distributed version of `npm` or install a set version of npm that supports node v9.x. At least fixed to major version (`npm i npm@^6`) but I prefer to use exact versions so build changes are in your control.

[Nodes active LTS releases](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) and [list of released node/npm versions](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/).